# Wordpress php switch statement not working, only first case triggers actions - multi submit

Tags: php, html, wordpress, forms, submit

I'm working on a WordPress plugin, I'm trying to insert data to DB.

I've used multi form and submit

```
<h1>Slider Menu</h1>
<h3>slider image 1</h3>
<form action="" method="post">
IMAGE URL: <input type="text" name="img" />
TEXT: <input type="text" name="text" />
URL: <input type="text" name="url" />
<input type="submit" name="action" value='s1'>
</form>

<h3>slider image 2</h3>
<form action="" method="post">
IMAGE URL: <input type="text" name="img" />
TEXT: <input type="text" name="text" />
URL: <input type="text" name="url" />
<input type="submit"  name="action" value='s2'>
</form>
```

I made a function & I made a switch case that call to this function.

```
<?php
    function update_slider_db($x)
    {
        require_once('../wp-load.php');

        global $wpdb;

        // SQL query and update
        $slider_img = $_POST['img'];
        $slider_title = $_POST['text'];
        $slider_url = $_POST['url'];

        $wpdb->update('wp_slider', array('img'=>$slider_img, 'title'=>$slider_title, 'url'=>$slider_url), array('id'=>$x));
    }

 //switch case which button is pressed
 switch(isset($_POST['action'])) {
    case 's1': 
    update_slider_db(1);
    break;
    case 's2':
    //$x=2;
    update_slider_db(2);
    break;
}
```

But unfortunately it always enters into the case 1.

I mean I can not update a row other than row 1 (No matter which SUBMIT I click - it only updates the first row)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your switch evaluates the "true" or "false" returned by the isset

```
if(isset($_POST['action'])
{
switch($_POST['action']) 
  {
  case 's1': 
  update_slider_db(1);
  break;

   case 's2':
   update_slider_db(2);
   break;

  }
}
```